# Using the t() function in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

So I have used the t function correctly e.g. t('hello world')
But I am not sure what else to do to get these strings translated. I tried looking at the hook_locale documentation, but I wasn't sure what a group was. Could someone help me find some documentation that would help me understand what I need to do after adding the t function?

Thanks.

```
function my_module_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
    ...
    if ($op === 'view') {
    $content .= '<h2><span style="color: white;"><strong>' . t('my holiday') . '</strong></span></h2>';
    ...
    $content .= drupal_get_form('cool_form');
    $block['content'] = $content;
    return $block
}
}
```

EDIT: added some code. Is this enough code?

Comment: try this : op='view' rather than 'list'

Comment: I added the if statement that I was using with op === view. Does that help?

Comment: I mean try this : `function my_module_block($op = 'view', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {`

Comment: yeah I tried that and I went to administer -> site building -> translate interface and then selected blocks in export template clicked export and there wasn't any text from my block.

Comment: Does the block shows original data? (I mean untranslated strings?)

Comment: Yes, and some html too. But I don't think that any of the text comes from my block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26720/discussion-between-will-and-alireza-tabatabaeian).

Comment: it tooks some times for tokens to be added to user interface , especially when you are working on localhost , import a pto file to your site containing those string and the string should be translated ,

Comment: Yeah I am working on localhost. Do you mean pot file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to Enable your proper language (using locale module) and then use translate interface (site building -> translate interface) , and you can translate your string.

after that whenever t('hello world') is called , drupal checks for proper language , then checks if there is a translation for 'hello world' in that language , if true , then it will print translated string.

Comment: Thanks looks like the issue lies elsewhere but this answer is correct.

Comment: I think a little more details may lead to a better answer . for-example your code snippet and your goal

Comment: I have created a custom module that uses hook_block to display everything which is placed in the context module. I tried to export but my strings Were not there

Comment: can you attach your code? so are you putting a variable in this function? if so how have you implemented the code?

Comment: +1 Your suggestion to change list to view in my code was the key to helping me with my needs. Thanks.